# JavaScript match error

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
var counter=0;
var output = "";

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  if ( list[i].className.match(/\bmodule\b/) ) {
    var header_text = list[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerText;
    var ul = list[i].getElementsByClassName('clips');
    var li_list = ul[0].getElementsByClassName('title');
    if ( li_list.length > 1 ) {
      output += "------" + header_text + "------" + "     ";
      for (var y=0; y<li_list.length; y++) {
        counter += 1;
        output += counter + " - " + li_list[y].innerText + "     ";            
     }}}}
console.log(output);
```

and getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

EDIT: prasad's answer fixed the initial problem but I am now getting similar issues with the getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName

EDIT: The general structure of the html is something like the following

```
<body>
...
  <section class="module">
    <header class>
      <div></div>
      <div class="side-menu-module-title">
        <h2 class="..."></h2>
      </div>    
    </header>
  </section>
 ...
</body>
```

Comment: provide your markup maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Simple typo. Please see @prasad's answer.

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when asking a question. Post a complete code sample so we can replicate the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing `i` on iterating the element.its a `list[i]`

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  if ( list[i].className.match(/\bmodule\b/) ) {
```

Comment: Thanks prasad. This fixed my initial error but now I am getting similar errors further down the code on getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `match` have a problem change the if condition with `if(ist[i].classList.contains('module'))` and try